# Why are substrings generated from a binary string pattern matching converted to integers?

Tags: elixir

It seems that parts of a binary strings originating from pattern matching are converted to integers:

```
iex(21)> <<type::size(8)>> = Base.decode16!("05")
<<5>>
iex(22)> type
5
```

I would expect `type` to remain a plain binary string, as after all the application knows what type of data the binary represents.

I was not able to find a way to keep the substring as binary strings. Is it a design decision or a limitation from Erlang implementation?

Comment: `<<type::binary>> = Base.decode16!("05")` will give you `type` as a binary string, what you are pattern matching in the question is telling the VM to return `type` as an eight bit integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't consider this behaviour surprising, I'd even say it's expected. I consider it a design decision rather than an implementation limitation.

It comes natural when you realize what a binary is - after the [Getting started guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries-and-bitstrings):

> A binary is just a sequence of bytes.

The primary syntax for creating binaries also showcases this:

```
<<97, 98, 99, 100>>
```

It's therefore natural that primary way of pattern matching is also byte (or in general integer) based.
Fortunately it's not the only option we have. There are many formatters and all are documented in [`Kernel.SpecialForms.<<>>/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1).

To get the behaviour you expect you need to use the `binary` type for your match (default unit for `binary` is 8 bits, so instead of `size(8)` you want `size(1)`):

```
iex(3)> <<type::binary-size(1)>> = Base.decode16!("05")
<<5>>
iex(4)> type
<<5>>
```